# XAML control changes position when running the app

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to build an app which requires me to put some simple text in a fixed position (let's say that I'm trying to simulate a LockScreen).

This works while I'm in the design mode, but the `TextBlock` changes position as soon as I run the app!

[image: Design Mode]

[image: Running]

As you can see from the previous images, in design mode my `TextBlock` overlays the background's one but, when the app runs, it's moved at the bottom of the screen.

The code is quite simple and I don't get what's happening!

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}">
    <Image Source="/bvlczww3.bmp" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="StaticDateBlock" Margin="32,645.263,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="374.737" Width="550" FontSize="113" Text="11:03 Saturday January 5" MaxWidth="540" MaxHeight="390" UseLayoutRounding="False" FontWeight="Medium" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight"/>

</Grid>
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: from where does this text comes from??? every other text is already on its position

Comment: Everything comes from the image, except the `TextBlock` that is moved on the bottom when the application runs. You don't see the `TextBlock` in the first image because its content is lined up with the tet from the image (you can see that, in the first image, the date seems bold because the text is overlaying). I've updated the firs image to show the `TextBlock`

Comment: reduce 645 to 320 and check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adjust the Margin of the TextBlock control... because when the application run the control change its position with respect to application.

Comment: I'll try it, but why design windows is so different from the actual app? I mean, in the design windows everything is perfect while in the app it's all messed up!

Comment: because every device has different screen size for better result u have to take percentage of screen resolution

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** use margins like this - `Margin="32,645.263,0,0"`, XAML was invented as a smart-placement app, so you should use panels, grids etc for align needed components, not to use absolute coordinates. Try panels and perhaps it will fix your problem.

Comment: You're right, but the problem here is that everything I do in the design windows is not what I get when the app is running! Even the font size, which is perfect in design mode, becomes bigger when the app is running!

Comment: What's about `SnapsToDevicePixels` option?

Comment: Are you sure that there's a `SnapsToDevicePixels` option on Windows Phone?

Comment: There's a `SnapsToDevicePixels` option on Silverlight